# Is there any way to get data from json url

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm working on android and I'm trying to parse json data from url to get the string from array.

I have tried using `volley` but i'm not getting the expected result.

```
{
code: 200,
status: "OK",
data: [
{
timings: {
Fajr: "04:13 (+04)",
Sunrise: "05:36 (+04)",
Dhuhr: "12:14 (+04)",
Asr: "15:42 (+04)",
Sunset: "18:51 (+04)",
Maghrib: "18:51 (+04)",
Isha: "20:15 (+04)",
Imsak: "04:03 (+04)",
Midnight: "00:14 (+04)"
},
```

---

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        try {
                            //JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

                            for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

                                JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                ModelActivity modelActivity = new ModelActivity(
                                        o.getString("Fajr")
                                        o.getString("Dhuhr"),
                                        o.getString("Asr"),
                                        o.getString("Maghrib"),
                                        o.getString("Isha")
                                );
                                modelActivityList.add(modelActivity);
                            }
```

I want `fajr` `dhuhr` `asr` `magrhrib` `isha` timings

any help will be appreciated

Comment: what is the problem using volley, can you share your code? or log trace.. that is where you can see what is wrong with fetching data?

Comment: Please share full json response.

Answer (score 0):

If your request returns the posted JSON then the problem is not `volley` library that does the request but the way you try to parse it.

In the JSON representation the `{}` mean that you have an object.
And the `[]` that there is an array.

So you should check at the first json object for the data element and then in this array for each object look for the timings and then the items.

Although I haven't compiled or run the code the parsing should be something like the following:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONArray data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
for(int j=0; j<data.length(); j++){
    JSONObject jObj = data.getJSONObject(j);
    JSONArray jsonArrayTimings = new JSONArray(jObj.getJSONObject("timings"));

    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){

        JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        ModelActivity modelActivity = new ModelActivity(
                o.getString("Fajr")
                o.getString("Dhuhr"),
                o.getString("Asr"),
                o.getString("Maghrib"),
                o.getString("Isha")
        );
        modelActivityList.add(modelActivity);
    }
}
```

For extra details on json parsing you should go through this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm)

Comment: JSONArray jsonArrayTimings = new JSONArray(jObj.getJSONObject("timings")); this line giving error Call requires API level 19 (current min is 15): new org.json.JSONArray

Comment: I guess there will be some equivalent for the older versions... personally I always use the `gson library` as my json objects are predefined and the parsing is less coding.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the JsonObjectRequest instead of the StringRequest.  Here is an example:

```
    public void getRate(String tripDate) {

    Rate = 0.54;

    String url = "https://myserver/api/rates/" + tripDate;

    JsonObjectRequest postRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {

                // since response is a JSONObject use getJSONArray to
                // get the JSONArray out of the JSONObject
                JSONArray rates = response.getJSONArray("rates");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Rate = 0.54;

                Log.i("Test", "Default Rate:" + Rate);

            }

        }
    },
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Test", "Response Error: " + error.getLocalizedMessage());
            Rate = 0.54;

            Log.i("Test", "Default Rate:" + Rate);


        }
    }) {


   @Override
   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String authValue = "Bearer ";
        headers.put("Authorization", authValue);
        headers.put("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
       return headers;
   }


};


MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(postRequest);
```

}

If your API returns a JSONArray, then you could use the JSONArrayRequest instead...

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET,
                    mJSONURLString,
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
```